# XML file menu help Android

Tags: android, xml

I'got a silly question. I've started to suffer this problem.

Usually when you're writing in the XML code, for example you write:

android:

and then a menu displays with all the options you can choose. The problem is that now that menu doesn't display. Other thing i've noticed is that all the code has changed this:

android:

Now is:

android1:

Has anyone found this before?

Thank you!

Comment: Weird. Menu option sometime doesn't show when you have some error in xml or corresponding layout. Check for that, or you have included that tag which are not available for that layout. ya but *android1* is really weird

Comment: Duplicate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" and xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android1"

Comment: Ohh. Then its better you put this is answer section and mark it as answer so that other users find it easy to get.

Comment: at last of this page you would see a section with **Your Answer**

write your piece of code there and click on Tick mark. that will accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the android1 part , but do check this.

In the Navigator in Eclipse, right click on the xml you are trying to open

```
Open with -> Android Common XML Editor.
```

Also if this does not work . Check

```
Window -> Preferences -> XML -> XML files -> Editor -> Content Assist
```

Make sure the check boxes related to suggestions are ticked. You could do a restore default on this menu

Answer (score 0):

The problem was i duplicated this:

xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";  xmlns:android1="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android1";